# Возможно ли создание адаптивной разметки только при помощи Flexbox?

Tags: html, flexbox

Большой экран:

```
 [a][c][d][e][f]
 [b][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

min 1000

```
[a][c][e]
   [ ][ ]
   [d][f]
[b][ ][ ]
```

min 600

```
[a]
[c]
[e]
[f]
[b]
```

блоки a и b вдвое меньше остальных по высоте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper>div {
  border: solid;
  width: 30%;
}

#a {
  order: 1;
  height: 45%;
}

#b {
  order: 2;
  height: 45%;
}

#c {
  order: 3;
  height: 100%;
}

#d {
  order: 4;
  height: 100%;
}

#e {
  order: 5;
  height: 100%;
}

#f {
  order: 6;
  height: 100%;
}

@media(max-width:900px) {
  #wrapper {
    background-color: red;
  }
  #a {
    order: 1;
    height: 45%;
  }
  #b {
    order: 2;
    height: 45%;
  }
  #c {
    order: 3;
    height: 45%;
  }
  #d {
    order: 4;
    height: 45%;
  }
  #e {
    order: 5;
    height: 45%;
  }
  #f {
    order: 6;
    height: 45%;
  }
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  #wrapper {
    background-color: green;
  }
  #a {
    height: 20px;
    order: 1;
  }
  #b {
    height: 20px;
    order: 6;
  }
  #c {
    height: 20px;
    order: 2;
  }
  #d {
    height: 20px;
    order: 3;
  }
  #e {
    height: 20px;
    order: 4;
  }
  #f {
    height: 20px;
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
  <div id="d">d</div>
  <div id="e">e</div>
  <div id="f">f</div>
</div>
```